# On('click') jquery doesn't work after page loaded with load() function

Tags: jquery

Is use a cookie to know which page to load inside my DIV

```
if($.cookie('logged') == null){
    $('#auction-form').load('pages/login.php');
}else{
    $('#auction-form').load('pages/bid.php');
}
```

But inside the login.php page, I have another link that would trigger another load() function which is not working.

```
$('.register-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('#auction-form').load('pages/register.php');
});
```

The .register-btn class is a link which should trigger the function above. I know this might be something that it's because when the login.php page is loaded, it's not in the DOM so the .register-btn can't be seen. How I could delegate the script on a page that is loaded from a load() function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','.register-btn',function(){
```

instead of

```
$('.register-btn').on('click',function(){
```

Since `.register-btn` does not reside on the DOM(dynamic element), you cannot bind the event directly.

For dynamic elements, the syntax is:

```
$(parentselector).on('event', 'selector', yourFunction)
```

*Note that `parentselector` needs to be a `Non-dynamic always DOM present element`*

Comment: Could this work with another load() inside another ? Always calling the $(document) is the key for a proper delegation ?

Comment: @Warface - I don't know how to express this correctly, but you need to call element.on() using an element that was originally in the DOM.

Comment: So using 'document' will make sure that it will scan all over the new DOM right?

Comment: @Warface - ideally, you should not write `$(document)`. That affects performance and that's the main reason why `live()` got deprecated. Use a parent selector which is always present in the DOM. Since, we don't know your DOM tree, `$document` is the best we can do. Follow the syntax above.

Comment: Well #auction-form should be always there since we load stuff inside of it no ? I should set a parent to that element you think ?

Comment: @Warface In that case, try this `$('#auction-form').on('click','.register-btn',function(){` and see if it works.