# javascript function disabled after route to other page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

i have html file that wraps react component , below is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content=""><!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/logo-fav.png"> -->
    <title>Loyalty Multipolar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/material-design-icons/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      .modal-body {
          max-height:400px;
          overflow-y:auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/lib/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/lib/jquery.niftymodals/dist/jquery.niftymodals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.niftyModal('setDefaults',{
      overlaySelector: '.modal-overlay',
      closeSelector: '.modal-close',
      classAddAfterOpen: 'modal-show',
    });

    $(function(){
      Plugins.init();
      $('.admin').click(function(){//button modal 
        alert('alert');
      });
    });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my admin page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import CreateForm from '../Component/Admin/CreateForm';

class AdminPage extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="be-content">
        <CreateForm/>
        <div className="page-head">
          <h2 className="page-head-title">Manage Admin</h2>
          <ol className="breadcrumb page-head-nav">

            <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li className="active">Index</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        <div className="main-content container-fluid">
          <div className="panel panel-flat">
            <div className="panel-heading">
              Admin
              <button data-modal="create" className="btn btn-space btn-primary pull-right md-trigger admin">Create New</button>
            </div>
            <div className="panel-body">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-overlay"></div>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default AdminPage;
```

my problem is :

i have page for admin, and within it there is a modal, i'm using modal to show a form , when we start page or type the route address from address bar eg:  `localhost:3000/admin` modal is showing and all javascript function such as alert that i put (see above html file) is fired, but if i access the page from sidebar link the javascript function is disabled or doesn't work, example

i access `/` from sidebar link then i click `/admin` and i click button to show modal it doesn't show modal.

i'm using react route v4 
and my question is exactly same like [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3256) but i want more simple,effective and efficient way.

Anyone can help? thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see any react component?

Comment: check above, i have added it

Comment: have you tried changing `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` to `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: what's difference ? , i've tried and also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in jQuery binding after DOM updates like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292057/onclick-jquery-doesnt-work-after-page-loaded-with-load-function) and you should rewrite this line:

```
$('.admin').click(function(){//button modal
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('','.admin',function(){//button modal
```